# How to acces an pixel value of an image in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, element, neural-network, pixel

i have an 1x128 grayscale image that i want to copy to an array/list.
When  i read out image i see it is only one index big: `n = len(res)`

I want to read out every pixel value and say if pixel I > 128 it must be 1. Else it must be 0.

```
for index in res:
        if res[h] > 128:
            res[h] = 1
        else: 
            res[h] = 0
        h = h + 1
```

But res has only one element and looks like this: `res = [[  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 128 255 255 255 255 255 255
  255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
  255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
  255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
  255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
  255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
  255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
  255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
  255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
  255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
  255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
  255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
  255 255 255 255]]`

I want this to have in an array, so that i can put every index (that is is convert(to an 1 or 0) to an input of an neural network.

Can someone explain how i can do this?
Here is an piece of my main:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
# Camera ID to read video from (numbered from 0)
camera_id = 0
dev = open_camera(camera_id) # open the camera as a video capture device

while True:
    img_orig = get_frame(dev) # Get a frame from the camera
    if img_orig is not None: # if we did get an image
        cv2.imshow("video", img_orig) # display the image in a window named "video"
    else: # if we failed to capture (camera disconnected?), then quit
        break

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_orig, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cv2.imshow("video1", gray) # display the image in a window named "video"
    crop = gray[310:410, 0:1280]
    gauss = cv2.GaussianBlur(crop,(5,5),0)
    (thresh, im_bw) = cv2.threshold(gauss, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
    cv2.imshow('frame2',im_bw)
    height1, width1 = gauss.shape
    res = cv2.resize(im_bw,(width1/5, height1/100), interpolation = cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
    height2, width2 = res.shape
    cv2.imshow('frame3',res)

    n = len(res)
    h = 0
    for index in res:
        if res[h] > 128:
            res[h] = 1
        else: 
            res[h] = 0
        h = h + 1
    #print "Binair is: %s" % img_binair
    print "image line is: %s" % res
```

Comment: Avoid for loops in python as far as possible. You can use numpy indexing. Try `y = np.where(x>127,1,0)`

Answer (score 0):

You have to avoid for loops in Python as far as possible, especially where you are with large arrays like images. It will be very slow.

If you are using Numpy, use Numpy indexing for better performance. [Read this](http://opencvpython.blogspot.com/2012/06/fast-array-manipulation-in-numpy.html)

In your case, you can use `np.where()`. I will show you one example:

```
In [10]: x = np.random.randint(1,255,(5,5))

In [11]: x
Out[11]: 
array([[ 71,  63, 219,  34,  73],
       [254,  19,   5,  25, 178],
       [165, 142,  20, 208,  61],
       [ 29,   3,  22,  26,  10],
       [ 11, 208, 147, 206, 186]])

In [12]: y = np.where(x>127,1,0)

In [13]: y
Out[13]: 
array([[0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1]])
```

Alternatively, since you are using OpenCV, you can directly apply [cv2.threshold()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?highlight=threshold#threshold) for this. I don't have OpenCV right now, so I can't show you example, but try below line of code.

```
ret, y = cv2.threshold(x, 127, 1, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
```

y is your output. ret is just some value. Ignore it right now. You can read more about [threshold here.](http://opencvpython.blogspot.in/2013/05/thresholding.html)